# asp.net application with Sharepoint Client OM

Tags: sharepoint

Sorry for my pool english!
How to pass webapplication's credentials to sharepoint by Sharepoint client OM?
(my webapplication use windows authenticationmode)
In my webapplication,I use the code:

```
  ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
  clientContext.Credentials=CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
  Web oWebsite = clientContext.Web;
  clientContext.Load(oWebsite,w=>w.Title);
  clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

return HTTP 401 error,so Is "CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials" only work in client application not web application?

Comment: What context is this code running in (silverlight, web part, desktop app, server app)?

Comment: server app,I bulid a asp.net web application with MVC3.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for web credentials:

```
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName,Password,Domain);
```

It would be nice to have your profile fulfilled so we could know which language to write! ;)